# PWA on Android: Hiding the top bar with the clock?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've got a manifest.json with

```
"display": "fullscreen",
"orientation": "landscape"
```

but when launched from the "install to home screen" icon, the very top bar with the clock and notification icons is still showing.  Any way to have a true-fullscreen option?

The chrome docs say I can also use "standalone" - but even with that, it still shows the top bar.

Hard to make an immersive game!

Comment: They are [working](https://ubiquitous-willow.glitch.me/) for me. Did you initially have a PWA with a different `display` value that you updated? The PWA install might be using the old `manifest.json` values. Try uninstalling the PWA from the device, clearing that sites data, and installing the PWA again.

Comment: Just to extend what abraham said, you can got to chrome://serviceworker-internals and play around.

Comment: @abraham I believe I did have it the other way at first - I'll try your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As abraham said in the comments, using `"display": "fullscreen",` is the correct way to do it.

If you change the `display` property after the PWA is installed, it could take up a day for Chrome to update and change the display mode. See [How Chrome handles updates to the web app manifest](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/#cr-android) for details on how manifest changes are handled.

During development, the best way to check how changes to the manifest are handled is by doing an uninstall/reinstall.